# condition execution using if or logic

Tags: c++

when using objects I sometimes test for their existence
e.g

```
if(object)
 object->Use();
```

could i just use

```
(object && object->Use());
```

and what differences are there, if any?

Comment: @Brian: No, he's using the short-circuit feature of `&&` to execute the second half of the expression only if the first half is true (non-NULL).

Comment: No, these are not equivalent - second may cause an error instead of doing what was intended. Also the first case is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're the same assuming `object->Use()` returns something that's valid in a boolean context; if it returns `void` the compiler will complain that a void return isn't being ignored like it should be, and other return types that don't fit will give you something like `no match for 'operator&&'`

Answer (score 5):

One enormous difference is that the two function very differently if `operator&&` has been overloaded.  Short circuit evaluation is only provided for the built in operators.  In the case of an overloaded operator, both sides will be evaluated [in an unspecified order; `operator&&` also does not define a sequence point in this case], and the results passed to the actual function call.

If `object` and the return type of `object->Use()` are both primitive types, then you're okay.  But if either are of class type, then  it is possible `object->Use()` will be called even if `object` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

They are effectively the same thing but the second is not as clear as your first version, whose intent is obvious.  Execution speed is probably no different, either.

Comment: That's incorrect. The second form will cause a compile-time error if e.g. the return type of object->Use() is void.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally they are the same, and a decent compiler should be able to optimize both equally well. However, writing an expression with operators like this and not checking the result is very odd. Perhaps if this style were common, it would be considered concise and easy to read, but it's not - right now it's just weird. You may get used to it and it could make perfect sense to you, but to others who read your code, their first impression will be, "What the heck is this?" Thus, I recommend going with the first, commonly used version if only to avoid making your fellow programmers insane.

When I was younger I think I would have found that appealing. I always wanted to trim down lines of code, but I realized later on that when you deviate too far from the norm, it'll bite you in the long run when you start working with a team. If you want to achieve zen-programming with minimum lines of code, focus on the logic more than the syntax.

Comment: *"if you want to achieve zen-programming with minimum lines of code"*... then I invite you to try Rebmu! :) http://hostilefork.com/rebmu/

Comment: Haha, that looks fun but it's an extreme example of exactly what I'm warning not to do. :-D Still looks amusing though, will have to give it a try.

Comment: Shell programmers seem like this sort of syntax, but I agree with you that it is not _currently_ idiomatic C++, or C. Jeesh, even the _ternary_ operator suffers from unnecessary criticism.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that. If you overloaded operator&& for pointer type pointing to object and class type returned by object->Use() all bets are off and there is no short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You see, C language, as well as C++, is a mix of two fairly independent worlds, or *realms*, if you will. There's the *realm of statements* and the *realm of expressions*. Each one can be seen as a separate sub-language in itself, with its own implementations of basic programming constructs.

In the realm of statements, the *sequencing* is achieved by the `;` at the end of the single statement or by the `}` at the end of compound statement. In the realm of expressions the sequencing is provided by the `,` operator.

*Branching* in the realm of statements is implemented by `if` statement, while in the realm of expressions it can be implemented by either `?:` operator or by use of the short-circuit evaluation properties of `&&` and `||` operators (which is what you just did, assuming your expression is valid).

The realm of expressions has no cycles, but it has recursion that can replace it (requires function calls though, which inevitable forces us to switch to statements).

Obviously these realms are far from being equivalent in their power. C and C++ are languages dominated by statements. However, often one can implement fairly complex constructs using the language of expressions alone.

What you did above does implement equivalent branching in the language of expressions. Keep in mind that many people will find it hard to read in the normal code (mostly because, once again, they are used by statement-dominated C and C++ code). But it often comes very handy in some specific contexts, like template metaprogramming, for one example.